# Binary Search python 3.5

Tags: python, runtime-error, binary-search, python-3.5

I'm trying to write binary search in python 3.5 but it wont work I'm not sure why.

```
def binarySearch(alist, value):

    first = 0
    last = len(alist)-1
    midpoint = (last//2)
    while binarySearch:
        if value == alist[midpoint]:
            return True and print ("found")
        else:
            if value < midpoint:
                last = midpoint-1
            else:
                if value > midpoint:
                    first = midpoint+1    
binarySearch([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],3)
```

if I put value as 4 it displays found, if I put anything else nothing happens and its stuck running doing nothing.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You never reassign `midpoint` in the loop

Comment: @wim   ah ok ill try that

Comment: I realize this is probably for class, but in general, don't write your own binary search. Python already has [the `bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) for that exact purpose.

Comment: yeah I understand but it will come up on my exam and they expect me to be able to write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User1915011 beat me to my answer. In line with his answer and @wim's comment, I have made the following changes your `binarySearch` method.

1. Changed the loop to use the `found` variable
2. Added an additional assignment to `midpoint` inside the loop
3. Ensure the loop terminates by adding `first<=last`
4. Return found after the `while` loop to indicate success or failure.

   ```
   def binarySearch(alist, value):

       first = 0
       last = len(alist)-1
       found = False
       while first<=last and not found:
           midpoint = (first + last)//2
           if value == alist[midpoint]:        
               found =  True 
           else:
               if value < alist[midpoint]:
                   last = midpoint-1
               else:
                   if value > midpoint:
                       first = midpoint+1  
       return found

   if binarySearch([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],3):
       print "found"
   ```

Comment: Thanks dude, much appreciated

Comment: @Jaco because you assign midpoint in the loop, there is no need to do it previously

Comment: Quick note, it doesn't recognize the last element with last = len(alist)-1, it recognizes it as the element before last. So on the example given it would think 7 is the last element and not 8? thanks.

Comment: `binarySearch([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],8)` seems to work ? In Python indexing starts at 0, so `a[len(a)-1]` returns 8 if a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Answer (score 2):

1. Your looping condition is just wrong `while binarySearch`?
2. You change value of midpoint only once instead you should be changing it every loop iteration.
3. You compare value with index (midpoint) and should be comparing with
   list value (alist[midpoint])
4. This is wrong: `return True and print ("found")` it will always return None.

Answer (score 0):

binary converters are also cool

```
num = int(input('please enter your number: '))  
list = []  
for i in (128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1):  
    if num >= i:  
        list.append(1)  
        num = num-i  
    else:  
        list.append(0)
print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed explanation how it works:

```
    def binarySearch(array, i):

    ## Binary search is the algorithm which is used to search an element in a sorted array

    ## The time complexity of the binary search is O(log n)
    ## Which means that in an array of length(2^(n-1)) elements we need to look at only n elements
    ## That is why we say that binary search algorithm runs in logarithmic time, which is much faster than linear time

    start = 0
    last = len(array)-1
    result = False

    count = 0 ## to debug

    print("\n******************************************************************\n")
    while(start <= last and not result):

        ## Debugger Begin
        mid = 0
        print("Loop number: ", count)
        print("Start element: ", array[start], " Position of Start Element: ", start)
        print("Last element: ", array[last], "  Position of Last Element: ", last)
        ## Debugger End

        mid = (start + last)//2 ## '//' indicates the floor division(ignores the value after the period) 
        if(array[mid] == i):
            print("***Mid***")
            result = True;
        else:
            if(i < array[mid]):
                print("***The value of the item:",i," we are searching for is LESS than the current middle element***")
                last = mid - 1
            else:
                print("***The value of the item:",i," we are searching for is GREATER than the current middle element***")
                start = mid + 1

        ## Debugger
        count = count+1
        print("Mid element: ", array[mid], "   Position of Mid Element: ", mid, "\n")
        ## Debugger

    print("******************************************************************")
    if(result == True):
        print("\nThe element:",i ,"is in the array")
    else:
        print("\nItem is not in the array")

    return result

## Array you want to search
array = [9, 11, 12, 21, 23, 34, 45, 49, 65, 98]

## Item you want to search in the array
i = 21

print("Searching the element: ",i , "\nIn the Array: ", array)
print("Length of the array is: ", len(array))

## Binary Search
binarySearch(array, i)
```